# URL in Array mode (MathJax)

Tags: support, mathjax

I'm trying to build a table with MathJax where one column is going to contain an external link. Unfortunately, as I can see in the math mode (MathJax) the link does not occur. It displayed in math mode as  [*linkme*][1] without the link.

Is there a way to use hyperlinks in Math mode?

```
\begin{array}{|l|c|c|l|}\hline
\text{Collision type} & \text{complexity} & \text{Year} & Reference \\ \hline 
\text{free-start collision} & 2^{57.5} & 2016 & [Steven et. al,  Freestart collision for full SHA-1][1]\\ \hline
\end{array}


[1]: https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/967.pdf
```

Comment: Markdown isn't parsed inside TeX. Try \href{url}{math} instead.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger `\href{url}{math}` doesn't work in Cryptography.SE.